# Istioctl Install Error unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3"

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am trying to install istio 1.4.0 from 1.3.2 and I am running into the following issue when I run the following:

`$ istioctl manifest apply --set values.global.mtls.enabled=true --set values.grafana.enabled=true --set values.kiali.enabled=true`

I'm following the instructions in the [documentation](https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/#download):

```
$ curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | ISTIO_VERSION=1.4.0 sh -
$ cd istio-1.4.0
$ export PATH=$PWD/bin:$PATH
```

When I run the istio manifest apply I'm able to install a majority of the components but keep getting the following message for each Istio specific CRD:

```
error: unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "DestinationRule" in version "networking.istio.io/v1alpha3" (repeated 1 times)
```

Is there a step I'm missing? I'm simply following the documentation so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: The command You listed worked fine on my cluster with istio 1.3.3 already running without any errors or warnings. The documentation you linked is for Istio Preliminary 1.5 version . I suggest following main istio [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/). You can run command `istioctl x analyze -k` to see if istioctl finds any problems with your istio mesh configuration. Also what infrastructure/platform do you use for Your cluster?

Comment: @PiotrMalec I'm on EKS however I was on k8s version 1.11, so I'll try updating the nodes, re-install and see if that fixes anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone runs into this issue check what k8s version your nodes are on (`kubectl get nodes`). Upgrading my EKS cluster from 1.11 to 1.12 fixed the issue when installing with `istioctl`

Also, I didn't notice this in their docs for installing 1.4.0 with `istioctl`.

> Before you can install Istio, you need a cluster running a compatible version of Kubernetes. Istio 1.4 has been tested with Kubernetes releases 1.13, 1.14, 1.15.

Comment: The error `unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "DestinationRule"` means the CRD was not correctly installed. Istio 1.4 supports Kubernetes 1.13-1.15 per https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/ (although it may actually work on 1.12, as you noted) so that is likely where the issue was